# Fragment slide out animation doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I have an android app in which I am loading another Fragment from one fragment on click of a button

```
Fragment fragment = new EditImagesFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction tran = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
tran.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push, R.anim.pop);
tran.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And I have push and pop (slide in and out ) kind of animations defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="1000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-1000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Now when i load fragment it slides in as expected but slide out animation doesn't work when i press back button and try to go back, I am supporting v14 and above API level.
Can anybody spot the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try

> setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)

instead of

> setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit)

According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), *enter* and *exit* animations **will not be played** on popping from back stack.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the 4 params method of `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(...)` instead of the 2.

also, since you use the native fragment api(api 14+), I suppose the animation xmls should be placed in the `animator` res folder.

Comment: they are in "animo" folder for 4 params method don't i have to specify other animations too ?

Comment: plz try ``(R.animator.in, R.animator.out, R.animator.in, R.animator.out)``

Comment: tran.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push, R.anim.pop, R.anim.push, R.anim.pop); is what i did and now for both in/out it slides only in (one direction)

Comment: what did you mean for one direction?

Comment: i mean its sliding in only one direction for both the things when it loads and unloads both times it slides in one direction

Answer (score 1):

## Try:

```
 fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_new_screen, 0, 0,R.anim.remove_fragment);
```

enter_new_screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" android:duration="500" /> 
</set>
```

remove_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="500" /> 
</set>
```

setcustomanimations method takes four parameters in case of fragment, mate i am not good in explainations but this is a workaround. give a try and let me know if it works.